# if statement doesn't trigger (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello and sorry if this was already asked.
I'm trying to program a simple lottery simulation (for learning propose)
Somehow my if statement doesn't trigger so no matter what the user enters, the program uses the second if statement, never the first if statement (you won).

Thank you very much for all your quick answers! Didn't expect so many ppl to help so fast. We found the solution!

Here is the code:

```
import random

lottonumbers = []
lottonumbers = list(range(1,51))

lottonumbersro = random.sample(lottonumbers, 6) #right ones

print(lottonumbersro)

active = True

while active:
    userinput = input('your numbers')

    if userinput == lottonumbersro:
        print('you won', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break

    if userinput != lottonumbersro:
        print('no luck today', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break

print('why isn\'t this stuff working')
```

Comment: `input` returns a string, so you need to convert it to an `int`

Comment: There is no `else` clause anywhere in the posted code, so no `else` is being executed, contrary to your claim.  Try to describe what you expect, and what you're seeing instead.

Comment: @jakub thank you! I changed line 13: userinput = int(input('your numbers'))
Now I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\software\coding\python\codes\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    userinput = int(input('your numbers'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '22 43 41 6 37 49'

Comment: @TomKarzes sorry for the confusion. I changed the else to a seperate if statement because I was hoping that would fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey your confusion is understandable as a beginner I too faced such issues and the solution is simple whenever you use the input method you are returned with a string so you just need to convert it to an interger as shown below

```
userinput=int(input('your number'))
```

Edit for taking multiple integer inputs you can use the following

```
userinput=list(map(int,input('your number').split()))
```

Let me walk you through:  `input().split()` returns a list of strings.

On which if you run the `map` function with `int` it will return a map of integers

To which we apply the `list` function to finally generate a list

Comment: Thank you! Yes I started programming a few days ago :) I changed the line as you said now I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\software\coding\python\codes\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    userinput = int(input('your numbers'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '22 43 41 6 37 49'

Comment: @ga2xb

hey gabriel looks like you are trying to get a list of integers as an input 

Here is what you need to do



userinput=list(map(int,input('your number').split()))



Let me walk you through what is happening



input('your number').split() returns a list of strings



the map function iterates over the list of strings and applies the int function to each of those strings 



thus it will return a map with intergers which the list function in the end converts to a list of integers




Do let me know if you have any more queries

Comment: thank you very much! this finally worked! Can you maybe edit your first comment so I can mark it as the solution? if thats how stack overflow works.
Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as others have mentioned, but different solution.  You can convert the lotto numbers to a `str` and then check the `input` against that.  This expects a certain format for input (`# # # # # #`) but checks that the user input matches the 6 numbers exactly, in order.

```
import random

lottonumbers = []
lottonumbers = list(range(1,51))

lottonumbersro = random.sample(lottonumbers, 6) #right ones

stringed = [str(i) for i in lottonumbersro]
stringed = ' '.join(stringed)
print(stringed)

active = True

while active:
    userinput = input('your numbers\n')

    if userinput == stringed:
        print('you won', lottonumbersro)
        break
    
    if userinput != stringed:
        print('no luck today', lottonumbersro)
        break
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! i changed the code as you said. Now it recognizes when you enter the right numbers (hurray!) although it prints:
28 20 5 2 22 45
you won [28, 20, 5, 2, 22, 45]
no luck today [28, 20, 5, 2, 22, 45]
why isn't this shit working

and if you enter the wrong numbers it doesnt print anything it just lets you try again

Comment: @ga2xb it sounds like you have an indent wrong, perhaps the second `if` statement is not within the `while` loop?  The code above (exactly) only prints "you won" if you are correct, and only "no luck today" if you are wrong (plus the winning numbers in either case).  The loop always breaks and you always have to rerun the code to try again

Comment: yeah it probably is smth like that. if i dont type it in but copy and paste your whole code it works! Thank you very much for all your time and effort. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the input from `str` to `int`. Furthermore `lottonumbersro` is a list, thus equality check with `userinput` will yield `False`. Thus you also have check for inclusion of the input in `lottonumbersro` instead of checking for equality.

Other issues are f.i. that the while loop ends if the variable `active` is `False`, while you set the variable `aktiv` to false in the if statements or that you set `active` **and** `break` the loop. Only one is needed.

```
while active:
    userinput = int(input('your numbers'))

    if userinput in lottonumbersro:
        print('you won', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break

    if not userinput in lottonumbersro:
        print('no luck today', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break
```

You could also simplify the code:

```
while active:
    userinput = int(input('your numbers'))

    if userinput in lottonumbersro:
        print('you won', lottonumbersro)
    else:
        print('no luck today', lottonumbersro)
    active = False
```

Comment: So isn't checking if the input is in the list of numbers, not that the user has entered every number (in order)?  I assumed OP wanted the latter but maybe they need to elaborate

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried your solution but somehow I still get a value error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\software\coding\python\codes\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    userinput = int(input('your numbers'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 25 27 18 11 19'

Comment: @Tom: From the information given in the question, I assumed that checking for a single number was meant. ga2xb: So you want to enter a list of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand what you are actually comparing.  Im going to assume that you are typing the input in as a string of 6 numbers? So right now, your getting:

```py
[14, 41, 27, 49, 42, 17]
your numbers: 1 14 32 45 47
no luck today [14, 41, 27, 49, 42, 17]
why isn't this working
```

This is because the `userinput` variable you have contains a `str` type and you are comparing it a `list` type. What we have to do is take that input `str` and make it a `list` of `int`.

You can try adding something like this in your while loop:

```py
while active:

    userinput = input('your numbers: ')

    user_numbers = [int(number) for number in userinput.split()]

    if user_numbers == lottonumbersro:
        print('you won', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break

    if user_numbers != lottonumbersro:
        print('no luck today', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break
```

Notice how a list comprehension can used to switch that `str` to a `list` of `int`.  Now when you try your comparison, it should work fine.

```py
[13, 20, 16, 12, 11, 50]
your numbers: 13 20 16 12 11 50
you won [13, 20, 16, 12, 11, 50]
```

Note that this solution will only work if the input string is numbers separated by only spaces.  You will need to change the logic if you want to account for things such as commas.  You can do this by modifying the line:

```py
user_numbers = [int(number) for number in userinput.split()]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
changed the code as you said, now the first if statement doesn't trigger again or he doesnt get which are the right numbers. he always prints no luck today

Comment: Cool glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can also get values separated by space, build list of integers and compare sets because order of numbers is not important:

```
import random

lottonumbers = []
lottonumbers = list(range(1,51))
lottonumbersro = random.sample(lottonumbers, 6) #right ones
print(lottonumbersro)
active = True

while active:
    userinput = input('your numbers separated by space:\n')
    userinput = userinput.split(' ')
    userinput = [int(ui) for ui in userinput]
    if set(userinput) == set(lottonumbersro):
        print('you won', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break

    if set(userinput) == set(lottonumbersro):
        print('no luck today', lottonumbersro)
        active = False
        break
```